# Excel Power Query: Using List.MatchAny on a column value

Tags: excel, list, matching, powerquery

In Excel Power Query, I have a table.  Column A has single numbers.  I want to mark those records where the Column A value matches a list.  A cutdown version of the problem is:

```
let
    TableA = Table.FromColumns({{1,2,4}}, {"A"}),
    ListB = {4,5,6 },
    DPart = Table.AddColumn(TableA, "IsInB", 
            List.MatchesAny(ListB, each _ = [A]))
in
    DPart
```

I get an error in the DPart line

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Number.
Details:
  Value=4
  Key=A
```

Apparently, the code is trying to access the [A] column of elements of the list, instead of the [A] column of TableA.

What's the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
let
    TableA = Table.FromColumns({{1,2,4}}, {"A"}),
    ListB = {4,5,6 },
    DPart = Table.AddColumn(TableA, "IsInB", 
            (x) => List.MatchesAny(ListB, each _ = x[A]))
in
    DPart
```

But I would prefer:

```
let
    TableA = Table.FromColumns({{1,2,4}}, {"A"}),
    ListB = {4,5,6 },
    DPart = Table.AddColumn(TableA, "IsInB", 
            each List.Contains(ListB, _[A]))
in
    DPart
```

Comment: Thanks, Marcel.  That is an excellent answer.  I appreciate that (a) It shows me the right way to wrap the '(x) =>' around List.MatchesAny, and (b) points me to an even better way to solve the underlying problem.