# Power Query Closures and Recursion; Textbooks on this?

Tags: excel, recursion, closures, powerquery, m

Can closures in the Power Query M language be recursive?

Functions can be recursive.  I name a function-query Fibonacci, defined as

```
(X) => 
let
    Fib = if X <= 1 then 1 else X + Fibonacci(X - 1)
in
    Fib
```

It works fine.  But when I try and stand it up within a single query, it loses:

```
let
    Fib = (X)=> if X <= 1 then 1 else X + Fib(X - 1),
    Source = Table.FromRecords({[X=1],[X=2],[X=3],[X=5]}),
    UseIntFib = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Fib", each Fib([X]) )
in
    UseIntFib
```

The resulting table is

```
1    1
2    Error
3    Error
5    Error
```

with the errors' message being 'Fib not found, did you forget to import a module?'

Is there any other way around this? Or, if I need a recursive function, does it have to be stood up as its own query?

**Meta queries** -- In M, is a locally defined function like

```
Fib = (X)=> if X <= 1 then 1 else X + Fib(X - 1)
```

called a *closure*, or a *lambda expression*, or what?  I've seen 'em used, just not heard 'em *named*. So I'm unsure how to search for posts about them.

Is there a good textbook or online source that would teach me all about Power Query closures?  My go-to text, *M is for (DATA) Monkey*, says almost nothing about them.  Mostly, I'd just like a whole bunch of examples. I want to know about

- When to use them
- Recursion and mutual recursion
- How they relate / compare to using *each*
- Multi-statement closures - using *let* inside a *let* .
- Debugging them

Comment: If you will be so kind to respond to my answer to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623765/excel-power-query-using-list-matchany-on-a-column-value
I will consider reacting on this new question.

Comment: Done, and thanks.  I'm still learning my way around StackOverflow; sorry I didn't respond promptly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a function recursively, you need to add a @ as so called "scoping operator", so this code is OK (I just added @ to "Fib" in your code):

```
let
    Fib = (X)=> if X <= 1 then 1 else X + @Fib(X - 1),
    Source = Table.FromRecords({[X=1],[X=2],[X=3],[X=5]}),
    UseIntFib = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Fib", each Fib([X]) )
in
    UseIntFib
```

You can find more information in the Power Query Language Specification (October 2016): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt807488.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

(3.3.1 page 28, 6.3  page 58, and last but not least 9.4/9.5 on pages 91/92).

Comment: Thanks Marcel, both for the code-fix and for the references.  Y'know, I'd downloaded the Language Spec when I first started learning M, but I'd just been overwhelmed when I tried to understand it. (Too much, too soon.)  After your note, I dug it out and read where you pointed.  It's making a lot more sense to me now.